# Vue Router doesn't find my children route

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I am currently building an app that has the following hierarchy: Each user has some workspaces, and each workspace contains a number of tables. After the user clicks on a workspace, and then selects a table, the url should look like this: localhost/<workspace_id>/<table_id>

This is the router.js file:

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: 'home',
    path: "/",
    component: HomePage,
    children: [
      {
        name: "home.workspace",
        path: ":workspaceId",
        component: WorkspacePage,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This is how I navigate to a specific workspace:

```
@click="
          $router.push({
            name: 'home.workspace',
            params: { workspaceId: workspace._id },
          })
        "
```

However, whenever I click on this navigation, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: No match for
 {"name":"home.workspace","params":{"workspaceId":"3"}}
```

What exactly am I missing here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What you have [should work](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/andrei-gheorghiu/vue-router-example/draft/strange-goodall?workspaceId=31605654-0ddd-4181-8f09-54c47e491141&file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue). Consider setting up a *runnable* [mcve] featuring the bug. Without a repro, your question is not answerable, therefore not useful for anyone, including yourself, therefore *off-topic*.

Comment: Okay, understood. Will do this later today. Thank you for your time!